# Independent scroll between 3 columns

Tags: javascript, css, wordpress, scroll, multiple-columns

I want to do an independent scrolling between 3 columns on a Wordpress site, but I really don't know how can I do that, and what is the better langage to use (JS, CSS?). 
I have two sidebar with content, you have to scroll to see the last content in the sidebars. 
I have a container at the center with news and when you are at the bottom, you have an infinite loading. 
What I want to do it's when user scroll on the page, the sidebars and the news content are scrolling, but, when there are no more contents in the sidebars, they become "fixed" and just the news container is scrolling.
Like this : [image]

Can you help me please ?

Comment: After getting the layout setted up, just add a style called (overflow:scroll) to all three div(or the particular tags you use) where you want a scroll option.

Comment: So if my cursor is in either of those 3 areas and I scroll with my scroll wheel, each area should scroll independently? But if my cursor were in the header, or I was using the browser scroll bar on the right, all 3 areas should scroll? I'm not sure I've ever seen that functionality before. That's what I got out of your title.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you'd simply have to do to create an independant scrollbar for each of these is to set an `overflow: scroll;` property on the right selectors however, the downside is that just setting overflow could potentially cause a horizontal scrollbar too.

There is an unstable yet broadly adopted alternative which is [`overflow-y`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overflow-y) - [`overflow-y`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overflow-y) works like overflow but only vertical.

So setting `overflow-y: scroll;` will allow at best a vertical scrollbar to appear.

Doing this with JS is not recommended as it will clog your scroll which CSS doesn't.

The reason JS clogs your scroll is because in JS you'll have to listen for a scroll event, when the user scrolls these are fired usually multiple times per second, and with 'multiple' I actually mean 10 to 100 times. So imagine executing even a little bit of code, if that code is bugged anywhere you can say goodbye to your users because they will have such slow scrolling.

The mechanism for having custom scrollbars on a page exists but it's not widely adopted either - just because of this reason. The concept was good but it was just detrimental to the end-user.

The downside for CSS scrollbars is that they will default to the browser scrollbar which will be different in every browser and unfortunately styling these is implemented differently across all of them and quirky at best.

**NOTE**

If your website is fullscreen and all three columns scroll independently the user will have to do 3 times the amount of scrolling before he or she sees ALL the content on the page, this might not be what you want. Also if you're stacking these constructions vertically on the same page you'll only be able to scroll down further once you've scrolled past the end of atleast one block of content.

This will agitate your users when they don't want to see the top content but just the bottom content for example.

IMO I wouldn't go for a solution like this if my website is full-width since it will annoy your users but then again, I do not know the entire context of what you're trying to achieve.

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for reply. Just to be clear, I want to do exactly this : http://www.eurosport.fr/

Comment: They are using a different approach, instead of having 3 seperate components they have 2, the left part and the right part where the right part clips to the top after being scrolled so far. This gives a different effect from what you'll achieve with my solution. You can use JS for something like this since it's not possible using CSS only.

Comment: Ah ... Because it's what I want, It was my inspiration. I will try with CSS first

Comment: With CSS you'll get nowhere near the desired result so I would drop that to save you from some brain-pain there. I would recommend you spend your time researchning how to efficiently listen to the scrollhandler so that you can do this without clogging scroll (which isn't as easy as it sounds ^.^)

Comment: OK, I'm gonna check with JS, maybe in jQuery

Comment: I have created this, I have to integrate it in my theme now.

https://jsfiddle.net/p7ry0ynq/3/